# msysgit not accepting passphrase of private key

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys, msysgit, openssh

I'm trying to push a git repository from a Windows 7 machine to a Ubuntu 12.04 server using msysgit.

When using putty I have to choose the private key directly through the menu. It asks me for the passphrase and connects perfectly afterwards.

For msysgit I have set up a ssh config file, because the private key doesn't have the default name:

```
Host RemoteServer
  HostName remote.server.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/remoteserver_key
```

When I now try to push, msysgit asks me for the passphrase (same behaviour for git bash and git gui) and I insert it. Then it askes me again and again. The path to the key displayed is correct. So it always asks three times for the passphrase (which is definitely correct) and then I get a

> Permission denied (publickey).

That's weird isn't it? Some idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: You mention PuTTY, but then you show an OpenSSH client configuration file. Which SSH client are you actually using for msysgit? plink.exe (part of the PuTTY package)? OpenSSH built for Windows (e.g. Cygwin)? In any event, you can use the -v option with both to see what's going on.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I'm just opening Git Bash or Git GUI. Didn't change anything after installing.

Comment: msysgit appears to come packaged with an OpenSSH/Cygwin build. So first, try adding to your SSH configuration file the line "LogLevel debug" (above the Host stanza). If the OpenSSH client in use by Git is reading that file, then it will start emitting debugging information as if you had used "ssh -v" when you do your push.